# How to write a bash and define awk constants in command line

Tags: bash, awk

As a part of my bash, I want to pass some constant from command line to awk. For example, I want to subtract constant1 from column 1 and constant2 from column 5

```
$ sh bash.sh infile 0.54 0.32

#!/bin/bash

#infile = $1 
#constant1 = $2
#constant2 = $3

cat $1 | awk '{print $1"\t"$2"\t"$3"\t"$4"\t"$5"\t"$6}'
```

thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As `awk` is it's own language, by default it does not share the same variables as Bash.  To use Bash variables in an `awk` command, you should pass the variables to `awk` using the `-v` option.

```
#!/bin/bash

awk -v constant1=$2 -v constant2=$3 '{print($1-constant1),($5-constant2)}' $1
```

You'll notice I removed `cat` as there is no need to pipe `cat` into `awk` since `awk` can read from files.

Answer (score 0):

you need to remove gaps when defining vaariables:

```
#!/bin/bash

infile=$1 
constant1=$2
constant2=$3

cat $1 | awk '{print $1 $2 $3 $4 $5 $6}'
```